# WinSCP timestamp as a user input/from file

Tags: batch-file, winscp

I have a WinSCP command in a batch file  as described below:

```
get -neweronly event_%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%_0000.db C:\events\test
```

What I want to do is set the `TIMESTAMP` from a user input (e.g. from a text file)
I do not want to use the current computer time - Is this possible?

If I put a date of `20180101` in a text file and import it, would this be the solution?

```
set /p TIMESTAMP=<Timestampdate.txt
```

Would I need to do anything to the `TIMESTAMP` in the `get -neweronly event_%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%_0000.db C:\events\test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to [use an environment variable in WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#variables), use syntax `%NAME%`. The `#yyyymmdd` part cannot be there, nor does it make any sense.

And while WinSCP will not override an existing `TIMESTAMP` variable with its own value, it's definitely better to use a different name, to avoid ambiguity. After all, your variable is just a generic environment variable, it has nothing to with [WinSCP `TIMESTAMP` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp).

In batch file:

```
set /p MYTIMESTAMP=<Timestampdate.txt
```

In WinSCP script:

```
get -neweronly event_%MYTIMESTAMP%_0000.db C:\events\test
```